# Separating Global/Heap/Stack accesses

Tags: heap-memory, stack-memory, memory-access

I am instrumenting a program on x86 platform to collect its memory references. The output is something like
`<instr address>,<read/write>,<data address>`. After the memory references are collected I need to separate the Global/Heap/Stack accesses in the obtained output. I can somewhat figure out the global variables of the program with hints from the objdump of the program(.bss/.data section). But what how can I find out that a given data address belongs to stack, heap or is a global location defined by a library?

Comment: Does your process have any sort of memory allocation strategy? There's conventions, but they vary from compiler to compiler, library to library, and OS to OS.

Comment: I am using different programs ...so the strategy might be differnet